# #import <string> in ios? Protobuf c++ in ios

Tags: c++, ios, string, protocol-buffers

I am trying to get protobuf into xcode 4 and work with ios 5. I've done other tutorials none have worked. I have used a script to compile the libraries into arm 7 architecture and then added them to my project. This is the only thing that has worked so far.

My issue now is that I am trying to use the c++ generated files; however, I am getting an error saying #include  -> lexical or preprocessor issue.

Any tips? It only showed this when I tried to run my project on the ipad. Before, it was fine with it.

Thanks. :)

// Generated by the protocol buffer compiler.  DO NOT EDIT!
// source: addressbook.proto

```
#ifndef PROTOBUF_addressbook_2eproto__INCLUDED
#define PROTOBUF_addressbook_2eproto__INCLUDED

#include <string>

#include <google/protobuf/stubs/common.h>
//#include "google/protobuf/stubs/common.h"

#if GOOGLE_PROTOBUF_VERSION < 2004000
#error This file was generated by a newer version of protoc which is
#error incompatible with your Protocol Buffer headers.  Please update
#error your headers.
#endif
#if 2004001 < GOOGLE_PROTOBUF_MIN_PROTOC_VERSION
#error This file was generated by an older version of protoc which is
#error incompatible with your Protocol Buffer headers.  Please
#error regenerate this file with a newer version of protoc.
#endif

#include <google/protobuf/generated_message_util.h>
#include <google/protobuf/repeated_field.h>
#include <google/protobuf/extension_set.h>
#include <google/protobuf/generated_message_reflection.h>
```

Update: This only breaks when I include it in an obj c file. I can make a Demo.h and include addressbook. Why can't I include addressbook.pb.h into an obj c file? Am I missing a setting somewhere? Which one?

Comment: Could you post a minimal example of some code which has the problem that you are describing?

Comment: Added part of addresbook.pb.h

Comment: Update: It only breaks if I include addressbook.pb.h in an obj c class.

Comment: Update: I believe changing my obj c file from .m to .mm fixed it.... Hopefully... :(