# Protocol buffers version error when trying to make Mosh source code

Tags: makefile, protocol-buffers

I've been trying to install Mosh (the mobile shell) on the following system:

```
[ptedder@ukch-dev-lndt03 mosh-1.2.4]$ cat /etc/*-release
CentOS release 5.3 (Final)
```

It configures okay, however when I try and make Mosh 1.2.4 (or 1.2.0) I get the following error:

```
make  all-recursive
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/ptedder/bin/mosh-1.2.4'
Making all in src
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/ptedder/bin/mosh-1.2.4/src'
Making all in protobufs
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/ptedder/bin/mosh-1.2.4/src/protobufs'
make  all-am
make[4]: Entering directory `/home/ptedder/bin/mosh-1.2.4/src/protobufs'
  CXX    userinput.pb.o
In file included from userinput.pb.cc:5:
userinput.pb.h:12:2: error: #error This file was generated by a newer version of protoc which is
userinput.pb.h:13:2: error: #error incompatible with your Protocol Buffer headers. Please update
userinput.pb.h:14:2: error: #error your headers.
make[4]: *** [userinput.pb.o] Error 1
make[4]: Leaving directory `/home/ptedder/bin/mosh-1.2.4/src/protobufs'
make[3]: *** [all] Error 2
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/ptedder/bin/mosh-1.2.4/src/protobufs'
make[2]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/ptedder/bin/mosh-1.2.4/src'
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/ptedder/bin/mosh-1.2.4'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

This was with Protocol buffers version 2.4.1 (suggested it might be hardcoded into mosh here [#import <string> in ios? Protobuf c++ in ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9389338/import-string-in-ios-protobuf-c-in-ios)) but I've tried using Protocol buffers version 2.3.0 and 2.5.0 as well and they all give the following error:

```
"This file was generated by a newer version of protoc which is
userinput.pb.h:13:2: error: #error incompatible with your Protocol Buffer headers. Please update
userinput.pb.h:14:2: error: #error your headers."
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 6):

Two years after this question was asked, I still couldn't find a good solution. I had the same problem, and eventually fixed it after some detective work. The problem was this: I had the latest version of protobuf from the git repo, https://github.com/google/protobuf. When I tried to build my project, it was throwing the error shown in qmp's answer,

```
#if GOOGLE_PROTOBUF_VERSION < 2004000                                           
#error This file was generated by a newer version of protoc which is...
```

I was building code that someone else wrote, and in their .proto file, they didn't specify a version. The default is `syntax = "proto2";` I added `syntax = "proto3";` to the .proto file just before the `package` declaration and removed all instances of the `optional` and `required` keywords, as they are not part of version 3 syntax. Then from the command line, I regenerated the protobuf output.

```
prompt@ubuntu$ protoc --cpp_out=. project.proto
```

This updated all the files generated by protoc to version 3, which solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at userinput.pb.h, you will notice it reads

```
#if GOOGLE_PROTOBUF_VERSION < 2004000                                           
#error This file was generated by a newer version of protoc which is
```

So protobuf-2.4.1 is sufficient for mosh-1.2.4. If you still get the error, then there may be a stray protobuf installation, likely something in `/usr/local`.

Comment: userinput.pb.h is not shipped with Mosh. It is generated at build time by the protoc program. You need to make sure that the version of protoc matches the version of your protobuf headers.

Comment: My system running protoc version3.0.0 but lib I'm using to build for android [V2.6.1](https://github.com/julienr/protobuf-android)..n this is where I got stuck...Any suggestion!